# one of three php sessions not setting

Tags: php, session, isset

I have working session variables of `username` and `password` for login in, but when I try to add another session to show an `attempt` at login, it doesn't register. What I have working so far is this:

```
        // other php above where I do a query 
        session_start(); 
        if ($numrows == 0){ 
                //echo "no users matching that query\n";        
                unset($_SESSION["username"]); 
                unset($_SESSION["password"]);       
                header ("location: welcomepage.php");    
        }   
        else {
                //echo "congradulations, you have loged in\n"; 
                $_SESSION["username"] = $usernameSanitized; 
                $_SESSION["password"] = $passwordHashed;
                header ("location: welcomepage.php");    
        }   
?>
```

and in my `welcomepage.php` I have.

```
<?php
        session_start(); 
        if (isset($_SESSION["username"])&&isset($_SESSION["password"])){
                echo "hello".$_SESSION["username"]."\n"; 
        }    
        else{
                echo "you have not yet logged in"; 
        }   
?>
```

This is fine, but for some reason, where I run into problems is when I try to add another third session to try to mark where user tried to login, called `$_SESSION['attempt']`.

In the first part of my code for the login, I add:

```
        // other php above where I do a query 
        session_start(); 
        $_SESSION["attempt"] = "attempted"; //<----added this line
        if ($numrows == 0){ 
                //echo "no users matching that query\n";        
                unset($_SESSION["username"]); 
                unset($_SESSION["password"]);       
                header ("location: welcomepage.php");    
        }   
        else {
                //echo "congradulations, you have loged in\n"; 
                $_SESSION["username"] = $usernameSanitized; 
                $_SESSION["password"] = $passwordHashed;
                header ("location: welcomepage.php");    
        }   
?>
```

And then I add another conditional:

```
<?php
        session_start(); 
        if (isset($_SESSION["username"])&&isset($_SESSION["password"])){
                echo "hello".$_SESSION["username"]."\n"; 
        }   
        else if (isset($_SESSION["attempt"])){ // <--- added this condition
                echo "login with username and password failed";  
                unset($_SESSION["attempt"]);        
        }   
        else{
                echo "you have not yet logged in"; 
        }   
?>
```

But when I enter with a wrong username or password, I'm always directed to `"you have not yet logged in"`. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any whitespaces before `<?php` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

I found a much better solution to my problem. I don't know why my conditional wasn't registering the session variable as `isset`, but my purpose was to send a variable depending on the login status (fail or success). I did this by doing the following:

```
        // other php code above
        $_SESSION["usermessage"] = "";  // set this depending on outcome         
        if ($numrows == 0){
                //echo "no users matching that query\n";        
                $_SESSION["usermessage"] = "sorry, login failed";     
                unset($_SESSION["username"]); 
                unset($_SESSION["password"]);   
                header ("location: frontpage.php");     
        }   
        else {
                //echo "congradulations, you have loged in\n"; 
                $_SESSION["usermessage"] = "you have logged in!"; 
                $_SESSION["username"] = $usernameSanitized; 
                $_SESSION["password"] = $passwordHashed;
                header ("location: frontpage.php");     
        }   
?>
```

and as well on my `welcomepage.php`, I could have tested a conditional based on the value of my `$_SESSION["usermessage"]` as well if I needed to, but instead I just displayed it with different values.